# VBA: need to read accented characters from a text file and KEEP them

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use VBA to read text files, extract relevant data and transer to an Excel file. This is the type of code I'm using:

```
Sub ReadText()
Dim myFile As String, textline As String
myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Open myFile For Input As #1
LineNumber = 0
Do Until EOF(1)
    LineNumber = LineNumber + 1
    Line Input #1, textline
    'do stuff to extract the info I want and transfer to Excel
Loop
Close #1
End Sub
```

I'm living in a Spanish-speaking country so there is a lot of accented characters which I need to keep. The problem is that these accented characters are being converted to other characters. For example, what should be read as **INGLÉS** is read as **INGLÃ‰S**

I've seen there are solutions for replacing accented characters, but I don't want to do this because the accents are still needed for what I want to do with the info in Excel.

Am I missing a format option somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to do it is by using ADO.

```
Sub ReadUTFFile()
    Dim objADO As ADODB.Stream
    Dim varText As Variant

    Set objADO = New ADODB.Stream
    objADO.Charset = "UTF-8"
    objADO.Open
    objADO.LoadFromFile "C:\Users\pankaj.jaju\Desktop\utftest.txt"

    varText = Split(objADO.ReadText, vbCr)
    Range("A1").Resize(UBound(varText) - LBound(varText)).Value = Application.Transpose(varText)
End Sub
```

*Note* - Dont forget to reference Microsoft ActiveX DataObjects.

[image]

[image]
Sample test

[image]

Comment: PS - Not sure what these Spanish words mean as I copied them from internet. So be warned if they are offensive.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try, but how do I reference Microsoft ActiveX DataObjects?(the spanish words are inoffensive :)

Comment: You can avoid adding a version-specific library reference to the project (which makes distributing it challenging) by declaring and setting a reference to the stream as follows: Dim objADO As Object : Set objADO = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function i used to keep/ force to stop auto formating

```
Sub spcChr
Dim i As Long
Dim num As Integer
Dim x() As Byte
x = StrConv([A1], vbFromUnicode)
For i = 0 To UBound(x)
Select Case x(i)
    Case 211: num = 79
    Case 63: num = 83
    Case Else: num = x(i)
End Select
[B1] = [B1] & Chr(num)
Next
End Sub
```

Here A1 cells containing the names with special characters. B1 is for processing.